# Rotate MKMapView in iPhone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, mkmapview

I do not want any code but want to get reference for MKMapView compass rotation as shown in http://vimeo.com/7970239.

Can anyone tell me that is it possible or not?

Please help me to solve this problem..

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is certainly possible, here is the very line that makes it work:

`[self.map setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-1 * newHeading.magneticHeading * M_PI / 180)];`

In order to receive the heading events, you need to create a `CLLocationManager` and do `[locationManager startUpdatingHeading];`

Hope it helps you

Comment: @Mehul Mistri I am pretty sure you can. Have you tried it? What's wrong with it?

Comment: @frowing, thanks! This helped me with an issue where despite me explicitly setting `MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading`, the system would somehow set it back to `MKUserTrackingModeFollow`. Your solution is much better for my needs. Thanks!